# vuejs transition inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a transition in vuejs but this one only work when for ends, and only the leave transition works, the enter transition doesn't

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in imagesList">
  <transition name="fade">
    <div class="ctn">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img :src="item.url" :alt="item.alt" :title="item.title">
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <p>{{ item.info }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>
```

The css code is the one from the vuejs documentation:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: can you post the CSS for your transition?

Comment: @TimWickstrom sure

Comment: Thanks. See below for the solution and a working example.

Comment: @저Nash: Why delete [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60161596/772868)?

Comment: @false I thought it was better to try to solve alone and not bother with that question :/

Comment: @저Nash: The idea on SO is to show others your questions, too.. you were not that far amiss anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to add the appear attribute on the transition tag to force Vue to apply the transition when it is initially rendered.

Here is a working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-rjmi9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

You may need to click "refresh" in the IDE browser to see the transition. Depends on the speed in which your browser loads the IDE itself.

More information can be found at: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitions-on-Initial-Render

You may also want to consider using `<transition-group>` depending on your needs. Info can be found here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions